# Show A Form Side/Side Or Top/Bottom Of Parent Form C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I need to put my progress/status window/form just below of the parent form or left/right side of the form.

It's very basic things and i know how to do that.. (the formal/basic way)..

Here is my code:

```
frmMain oTest;

oTest = new frmMain();
//oTest.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; (to make child form border/title bar less)
oTest.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
oTest.Left = this.Left;
oTest.Top = this.Top + this.Height;
oTest.Width = this.Width;
oTest.ShowDialog();
```

But the problem is there is slight gap in between them.. please check the screenshot..
[image: Side/Side Gap]

And if i try to set the child form border style to none, then the appearance became worse than above, though for my purpose i need to make the child form border style to none.

Here is the screenshot for that case:

[image]

Based my knowledge, it's look like windows theme/style change the visible appearance of the form look bit smaller where the original size is bit bigger than that?

so, my question is how i can make the child form same size as the parent form size regardless of the os theme?

thanks in advance

Comment: The shadow around a modern form is part of the form size. Not sure what to do about that

Comment: The original gap doesn't look terrible to me.  Set both forms to no border to make them kiss.

Comment: @LarsTech, thanks for your reply sir, but for my needs it's not look nice.. and also it's not possible to make the parent form border less :(

Comment: But without a borderless form, you don't control what the border looks like, Microsoft does, and Microsoft does change the border appearance all the time, along with the border measurements.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my test, I reproduced your problem. I find that the form border width will affect the final result.

You could use the following code to get window border width.

```
 int windowBorder = (this.Width - this.ClientRectangle.Width) / 2;
```

Completed code:

```
 private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 oTest;


            oTest = new Form1();
            //oTest.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; (to make child form border/title bar less)
            oTest.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            int windowBorder = (this.Width - this.ClientRectangle.Width) / 2;
            oTest.Left = this.Left;
            oTest.Top = this.Top + this.Height-windowBorder;
            oTest.Width = this.Width;
            oTest.ShowDialog();

        }
```

Result:

[image]